# Migration of Primefaces 5.1 project from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

My primefaces 5.1 mobile application works just fine with Tomcat 7, but once I run it in Tomcat 8 all the `<p:commandButton>` need to be pressed twice before the `actionListener` is triggered. No errors are displyed.

Here is part of my code having this problem:

```
 <h:form rendered="#{!sessionManager.loggedIn}" id="login">
    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="#{msg.username}"/>
    <p:inputText id="username" value="#{sessionManager.username}"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msg.password}"/>
    <p:inputText id="password" value="#{sessionManager.password}" type="password"/>

    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.request_login}" styleClass="ui-btn-blue ui-nodisc-icon" actionListener="#{sessionManager.login}"/>
  </h:form>
```

And the `sessionManager.login` method signature is:

```
public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)
```

with the proper import `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;`

The first time a `POST` request is send with the following data:

```
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:page-content:login:j_idt89
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
page-content:login:j_idt89:page-content:login:j_idt89
page-content:login:username_input:a
page-content:login:password_input:a
page-content:login_SUBMIT:1
```

while the second time the same request but with some extra data:

```
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:page-content:login:j_idt89
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
page-content:login:j_idt89:page-content:login:j_idt89
page-content:login:username_input:a
page-content:login:password_input:a
page-content:login_SUBMIT:1
javax.faces.ViewState:8EgC7hvJoXWgMHaUZxk5rx66APlnNueyP32ajDxbvc/i5ak....
```

The Response and Request Headers are identical for both requests. There is no response I can read from Chrome, except for the second request that returns a new page after login.

Here is also a preview of the network tab in Chrome, where `findDetails` is the page returned after login:

```
Name              Status  Type      Initiator 
index.jsf         200     xhr       jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
index.jsf         200     xhr       :8080/serverwebapp/javax.faces.resources/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
findDetails.jsf   200     document  :8080/serverwebapp/javax.faces.resources/primefaces-mobile.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
```

Any idea what may be causing this? Are there any known issues with Tomcat 8? Thanks

Comment: What exactly happens on 1st click? Which request is sent and which response did it return? Pay attention to headers too.

Comment: It looks like the page is refreshing. Only the getUsername() and getPassword() methods are called.

Comment: Ugh. Which request and which response?

Comment: Just added more details to the description of the question. Sorry for my previous incomplete answer.

Comment: So a parent component of the login form is being re-rendered by another ajax request beforehand?

Comment: The login form is added to my index.xhtml with an include:

Comment: Is a parent component of the login form is being re-rendered by another ajax request beforehand? Yes or no? If yes, then that would explain the problem, particularly if that was fired by a `<f:ajax>`. This all is not visible in the information provided so far as that's far from being in proper MCVE format. You would do yourself and our a lot of favor if you simply followed http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info This will speed up generating answers.

Comment: The login form is added to my index.xhtml with an include: <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/snippets/login.xhtml" and it does not have any parent container except <ui:define name="main-content"> so no, it is not being re-rendered by another ajax request beforehand.

Comment: Well, then I can't explain why the view state is missing in there. At least, that's the root cause of your problem.